# What does it mean "(unregistered)" after username?

Tags: support

I visited a [new user profile](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/4596/susan) and immediately after the user name the word "**(unregistered)**" appears.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that they haven't registered with the site yet. They won't be able to log into that account from any other computer besides the one that has the cookie from stackexchange.

Reference: [What does it mean when someone's an Unregistered User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/what-does-it-mean-when-someones-an-unregistered-user)

Comment: They can, by carrying around the cookie in a text file. Some people seem to get along with that rather than put the effort to registering.